# Using grep to move files, Mac

Tags: linux, mac, terminal, grep, kerio

I want to do a search using grep inside all the files of a directory for the pattern '@mail.ru>' (to clean up a mess from a spammer).  Using Mac OS X's command line, which should be similar to most linux installs, how do I write the command to find all with that pattern, and move it to another directory called 'suspects'?
Thanks!

Neil

Answer (score 1):

Create the `suspects` directoy.  Then try a command like:

```
mv $(grep -l '@mail.ru>' *) suspects
```

Try the grep command on its own to see what it will find.  `-l` causes grep to list the matching file names.  This will only work if there are no spaces in the file names, which should be the case for mail files.  Otherwise you should look at using `find` or changing IFS to exclude spaces while you run the command.

Comment: Useful -- thanks!  In the end, I went with this:

grep -l -r -i -z '@mail.ru[<>]' 2a | xargs -I{} mv {} 2a-ru

where [<>} gave me a choice of < or > at the end of mail.ru (part of identifying the bad mail).  And 2a was the folder to be searched, and 2a-ru was for all the mail found to match the pattern.

Comment: For safety, it would be good to add `-n/--no-clobber` or `-i/--interactive` to mv. For example, when adding an -r to grep, or using `*/*` instead of `*`, it could go very wrong...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.